# What is the most fitting thread model to redesign a sequential linear search algorithm?

Tags: parallel-programming

Let's say that there is a simple **sequential algorithm** that performs a **linear search** of a unique key in an array:

```
public class SearchSeq {

  public static int search(int[] a, int key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if(a[i] == key)
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
 }


public static void main(String[] args) {

   int[] a = …; // an array with n elements
   int key = …; // the key to be searched within a

   long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

   int pos = search(a, key);

   long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
   long duration = stop - start;

   if(pos > 0)
     System.out.print("found " + key + " at " + pos); 
   else 
     System.out.print(key + " not found"); 

  System.out.println(" within " + duration + "ms");
 }
}
```

What will be the most fitting **thread model** in order to redesign the algorithm to **run in parallel**?

> In my opinion the most fitting thread model would be the Master/Worker because in this way we would divide the array into segmenets and search in parallel inside of each segment for the key. Smaller array size -> faster results.

**Edit 17/01/2021:** The thread models that I have in mind are:

- Master/Worker
- Producer-Consumer
- Pipes & Filters
- Peer to Peer

What do you think?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about details, unless you are doing some fine-grained optimizations. Try to implement something and then profile and compare the algorithms using as much realistic data as possible.

Comment: Also depends on what you think the behaviour should be if the key exists multiple times in the array.

Comment: @PhilipKendall thanks for the comment. My question, as stated in the description, is for the simple case that the key is unique.

Comment: "Thread model" can mean different things on different levels of abstraction. What do you mean by this term? For example, which alternative models apart from "master/worker" do you have in mind?

Comment: @DocBrown Thanks for the question. I edited the post and added the thread models that I have in mind.